# Java regex enclose words in brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have the following input string:

```
flag1 == 'hello' and flag2=='hello2'
```

(the string length and == 'something' varies).

Desired output:

```
flag1==("hello") and flag2=("hello2")
```

I have tried

```
line = line.replaceAll("(\\s*==\\s*)", "(\"")
```

but that does not give me the end bracket. Any idea how this can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: I used @hwnd 's way to do it. Thanks everyone who replied :)

Comment: But how does that replace `spaces around ==`

Comment: @vks - I replaced the spaces around == with one more replaceAll()

Comment: My regex did it in one go in the first attempt :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, you could match everything between the quotes and replace.

```
String s = "flag1 == 'hello' and flag2=='hello2'";
s = s.replaceAll("'([^']+)'", "(\"$1\")");
System.out.println(s); // flag1 == ("hello") and flag2==("hello2")
```

If you want the whitespace around `==` replaced:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s*==\\s*'([^']+)'", "==(\"$1\")");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<===)\s*'(\S+?)'
```

Try this.Replace by `("$1")`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oC3qA3/6

or

```
\s*==\s*'(\S+?)'
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oC3qA3/7

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two steps of `replaceAll()`:

```
str.replaceAll("'(?=\\w)","('").replaceAll("(?<=\\w)'$?", "')");
```

Full code-example:

```
String str = "flag1 == 'hello' and flag2=='hello2'";
str = str.replaceAll("'(?=\\w)","('")
         .replaceAll("(?<=\\w)'$?", "')");

System.out.println(str); // prints flag1 == ('hello') and flag2==('hello2')
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    s = s.replaceAll("(=\\s*)'(.*?)'", "$1(\"$2\")");
```